# convert .mdf 2008 file to .mdf2005 file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I made a project in visual studio 2008 and attached a database to it...
But later on it installed visual studio 2010 and it automatically updated my project...
As now i reinstalled my windows and again approched to my project, it showed the following message when i double clicked my database file in the server explorer in vs 2008, vs 2008 sp1, vs 2010...
[image]

Comment: Alternatively could you upgrade the install SQL Server CE to the VS2010 version? That should still work from VS 2008 but would be able to read the database again.

Comment: Thanks for your sugession but what is sql server CE

Answer (score 0):

The only way to downgrade your database for SQL Server is to script out all the objects to recreate your schema on a previous version and bulk export/ import the data. Alternatively refer to backups.

Comment: Can u please tell me the steps